# Is SPMetal and LINQ to SharePoint worth using?

Tags: linq, spmetal

I have recently run into a number of issues with SPMetal and LINQ to SharePoint that is making me wonder if it is worth it. In what cases does it make sense to use SPMetal and in what cases does it not work so well?

Areas that I found that require more code/work:

- [Managed Metadata](http://simonovens.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/spmetal-and-the-managed-metadata-column-aka-taxonomy-field-control/)
- [Hidden fields](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38339/spmetal-parameter-file-and-oob-fields-like-created-modified-etc-not-created/66357#66357)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I avoid it, more work than it's worth. I asked similar a while ago: [Frustrated! Linq to SharePoint, choice values, losing spaces](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21750/frustrated-linq-to-sharepoint-choice-values-losing-spaces). Enjoy the read ;)

Comment: Mostly avoid use of SPMetal tool. For below reasons:

1. Its difficult to maintain - regeneration required everytime you change the list
2. Unnecessary coding overhead for the above scenarios.

Comment: Is there ever a time it is worth using? Like if the lists wont change as users wont have access to them?

Comment: Meh, the complexity of it all, it's just not worth it. Write a quick CAML query and then you can use Linq on the SPListItemCollection that gets returned for finer tuning or data manipulation.

Comment: I just wish there was a better way, queries in CAML are a pain to write and read especially when they get more complex.

Comment: True, have you seen the CAML Builder tools out there? They help create them much easier.